# A field or property with the name 'Id' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, boundfield

i am not sure what am i missing here? i just changed my sql statement and now it says that its not reading the "ID" can someone please help me out?

here is my html code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomerOrders" runat="server" Width="940px"  HorizontalAlign="Center"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"   AllowPaging="True" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnPageIndexChanging="gvCustomerOrders_PageIndexChanging">

<Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="Id" HeaderText ="Id" ItemStyle-Width="100" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="CustomerName" HeaderText ="Name" />    
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="CustomerPhoneNo" DataFormatString= "{0:(###) ###-####}" HeaderText ="PhoneNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="CustomerEmailID" HeaderText ="Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="Name" HeaderText ="Product" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="TotalPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" HeaderText ="Price" />


                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl ='<%# Eval("Id", "~/Admin/OrderDetails.aspx?Id={0}") %>'
                                Text="View Details" Target="_blank" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

and code behind:

```
public void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.[name] FROM  Products p INNER JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE cp.CustomerID = cd.Id FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS Name, cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID ,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress ,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod FROM CustomerDetails cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.[name] FROM  Products p INNER JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE cp.CustomerID = cd.Id FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS Name, cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID ,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress ,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod FROM CustomerDetails cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        gvCustomerOrders.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        gvCustomerOrders.DataBind();
    }
```

really lost on this on why its giving me the error

```
A field or property with the name 'Id' was not found on the selected data source.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
select DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.[name] FROM  Products p INNER JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE cp.CustomerID = cd.Id FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS Name, cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID ,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress ,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod FROM CustomerDetails cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id
```

doesn't return a column named `'Id'`

but you're binding `Id` column here:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField ="Id" HeaderText ="Id" ItemStyle-Width="100" >
```

I'm guessing you just need to include the 'Id' column from the customer table in your query:

```
select DISTINCT Id, STUFF((......
```

Answer (score 0):

See you have a `<asp:BoundField../>` with  `DataField ="Id"` and the query you are using will not fetch any column with name `"Id`, If you fetch that column means this error will be solved. Or remove that `BoundField` from the front-End if it is not needed in this scenario.

**Note :-** You should Provide all specified `DataField`s in the binding collection, which means you should fetch those columns through the query